# Generic multi-functor composition/pipelining in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pipeline, c++20, functor

Is it possible to achieve generic multi-functor composition/pipelining in C++ 20?

```
struct F{//1st multi-functor
  template<typename T> void operator()(const T& t){/*...*/}
};
struct G{//2nd multi-functor
  template<typename T> void operator()(const T& t){/*...*/}
};

F f;
G g;
auto pipe = f | g;//what magic should happen here to achieve g(f(...)) ? how exactly to overload the operator|()?

pipe(123);   //=> g(f(123);
pipe("text");//=> g(f("text");
```

EDIT:
I tried both suggestions (from @Some_programmer_dude and @Jarod42) and I'm lost in errors:

1. overloading operator|() like @Some_programmer_dude suggested

```
template<class Inp, class Out>
auto operator|(Inp inp, Out out){
    return [inp,out](const Inp& arg){
        out(inp(arg));
    };
}
```

generates:

```
2>main.cpp(71,13): error C3848: expression having type 'const Inp' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'void F::operator ()<F>(const T &)'
2>        with
2>        [
2>            Inp=F
2>        ]
2>        and
2>        [
2>            T=F
2>        ]
```

2. using directly a lambda instead overloading operator|() like  @Jarod42 suggested:

```
auto pipe = [=](const auto& arg){g(f(arg));};
```

generates:

```
2>main.cpp(86,52): error C3848: expression having type 'const F' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'void F::operator ()<_T1>(const T &)'
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _T1=int,
2>            T=int
2>        ]
```

Comment: You need an `operator|` function which takes an `F` object on the left-hand side and a `G` object on the right-hand. Then it could return a lambda that when called do what you want.

Comment: `auto pipe = [=](const auto& arg){ g(f(arg)); };` :-)

Comment: The argument type of the lambda is not the same type as the you try to call it with. You really need to use auto type deduction for the lambda argument. Right now, the argument type for the lamda is `const F&` (with the code you currently have). See the comment by @Jarod42.

Comment: "would lose some const-volatile qualifiers" is because your `operator()`s are not `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a quick little library.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

namespace ops {
  template<class D>
  struct op_tag;

  template<class Second, class First>
  struct pipe_t;

  template<class D>
  struct op_tag {
    D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
    D& self() { return *static_cast<D*>(this); }

    auto operator()(auto&&...args) const
      RETURNS( self()(decltype(args)(args)...) )
    auto operator()(auto&&...args)
      RETURNS( self()(decltype(args)(args)...) )
  };
  
  template<class Second, class First>
  struct pipe_t:op_tag<pipe_t<Second, First>> {
    Second second;
    First first;
    pipe_t( Second second_, First first_ ):
      second(std::move(second_)),
      first(std::move(first_))
    {}
    auto operator()(auto&&...args)
      RETURNS( second(first(decltype(args)(args)...)) )
    auto operator()(auto&&...args) const
      RETURNS( second(first(decltype(args)(args)...)) )
  };
  template<class Second, class First>
  auto operator|(op_tag<First> const& first, op_tag<Second> const& second)
    RETURNS( pipe_t<Second, First>{ second.self(), first.self() } )
}
```

It is considered rude to overload operators in a greedy way.  You only want your operator overloads to participate with types you specifically support.

Here I require that types inherit from `op_tag<T>` to indicate they are interested in being an operation.

We then modify your code a tiny bit:

```
struct F:ops::op_tag<F>{//1st multi-functor
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(const T& t){
      std::cout << "f(" << t << ")";
      return -1;
  }
};
struct G:ops::op_tag<G>{//2nd multi-functor
  template<typename T> auto operator()(const T& t){
      std::cout << "g(" << t << ")";
      return 7;
  }
};
```

adding the tag and return values (otherwise, f(g(x)) makes no sense unless g returns something).

And the code you wrote now works.

We can also add support for `std::function`s and even raw functions if you'd like.  You'd add suitable `operator|` overloads in `namespace ops`, and require people to `using ops::operator|` to bring the operator into scope (or use it with a `op_tag`'d type).

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/67n9Go5Wz).

Output:

> ```
> f(123)g(-1)f(text)g(-1)
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Yakk for providing a detailed and full working example! It does f(g(...)) instead g(f(...)) but I saw your "magic" :)
You're also right: the methods from multi-functors should return something... to have a value for the next functor in the pipe

Comment: @solo Hmm, I guess `first | second` makes more sense than `second | first` for `operator|`.  Should be easy to swap.  I was thinking of composition, not piping.

Comment: @Solo Changed the order of arguments to `operator|`, and does it `second | first` order now.

Answer (score 4):

You are nearly there with

```
template<class Inp, class Out>
auto operator|(Inp inp, Out out){
    return [inp,out](const Inp& arg){
        out(inp(arg));
    };
}

struct F{//1st multi-functor
  template<typename T> void operator()(const T& t){/*...*/}
};
struct G{//2nd multi-functor
  template<typename T> void operator()(const T& t){/*...*/}
};

F f;
G g;
auto pipe = f | g;
```

however there are some nuances that you've missed.

First off `out` and `inp` within the lambda are `const`, because the closure type has a `const` qualified `operator()`. Also the parameter type of the lambda should be `auto`, not `Inp`, otherwise you could only `pipe(f)`.

You are wanting to call `g(f(x))` for some `x`, but the return type of `f` is `void`, that will need to be something else.

The `|` you provide will be ambiguous with the arithmetic `|`.

```
struct some_type {};

template<typename F>
concept unary_invocable = std::invocable<F, some_type>;

template <unary_invocable Inp, unary_invocable Out>
auto operator|(Inp inp, Out out){
    return [inp,out](auto&& arg){
        return out(inp(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)));
    };
}

struct F{//1st multi-functor
  template<typename T> auto operator()(const T& t) const {/*... return something*/}
};
struct G{//2nd multi-functor
  template<typename T> auto operator()(const T& t) const {/*... return something*/}
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Caleth, your approach also worked and it is a bit simpler than Yakk's.. but I already marked the answer...
Anyway, for sure I'll come back with another idea I have in mind: push-style pipeline for multi-functors