# C++ push-pipeline with multi-functors

Tags: c++, templates, pipeline, functor

Is it possible to chain 3 or more multi-functors with in a pipeline functionality and an elegant syntax like pipeline?

```
struct Filter0{//multi-functor; will be the last one in pipeline
  template<Args...args> void operator()(Args&&...args){/*not important what is done here*/}
};

template<std::invocable F> struct Filter1{//intermediate filter forwarding to a multi-functor
  template<Args...args> void operator()(F&f, Args&&...args){
    /*do smtg and sometime call f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);*/
  }
};

template<typename Left, std::invocable Right>
auto operator|(Left left, Right right){//chains "something" with a multi-functor
    return [left,right](auto&& arg){
        left(right, std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
    };
}

Filter0 filter0;
Filter1<decltype(Filter0)> filter1;
auto pipe1 = filter1 | filter0;//OK
pipe1('x');//OK pushes 'x' down the pipeline

Filter2<decltype(Filter1)> filter2;//Filter2 would be something similar with Filter1
auto pipe2 = filter2 | (filter1 | filter0);//KO
pipe2('x');//KO
```

With or without parentheses in 1st KO line:

- with parens I think "(filter1 | filter0)" should somehow return a functor
- without parens I think "filter2 | filter1" should return somehow a partial function

Note: I can "chain" 3 or more filters if I provide "the next one" as ctor's argument for each intermediate filter and store it as member inside the class instead having as argument in each method, something like:

```
Filter0 filter0;
Filter1 filter1(filter0);
Filter2 filter2(filter1);
filter2('x');//this will push 'x' down the pipeline
```

but in this case they are "tight" with each other from declaration.
I would like them as "loose" as possible, "tight" only by type (or even not at all if possible)

You can play with a live example here: https://godbolt.org/z/6e8cfrbTo

**SOLUTION 1** (simple & short): move template argument from filter class to methods (thanks RedFog & Jarod42!)

**SOLUTION 2** (a bit more elaborated): make `filter|filter` operation an expression template (see https://godbolt.org/z/G9z3qfsj8)

Comment: Your issue is that `Filter2<decltype(Filter1)> filter2` is wrong, it would be `Filter2<decltype(pipe1)> filter2` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GeErv5cro).

Comment: Any reason that F is a template parameter of class and not of the function?

Comment: `std::invocable` is strangely used,: You expect `f()`, but call it with different kind of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key problem is that you demands `F`, the type of the functor which filter should receive, for parameter, but you actually provide a lambda expression.

```cpp
auto pipe2 = filter2 | (filter1 | filter0);
```

`pipe2` is `Filter2<Filter1<Filter0>>`, has parameter type `Filter1<Filter0>`, but you provide `[left,right](auto&& arg){ left(right, std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)); };` instead of an instance of `Filter1<Filter0>`.

the most simple solution is, to let template parameter `F` belong to `operator()` instead of filter itself. see [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mb45vb1EK).

Edit: I remove the all `std::invocable`, it doesn't preform as it should be. I think the `std::invocable` constraint in `operator|` implies you want `filter | value`, so that `filter | (filter | (... | value)...)`, but it's impossible, the filters you design don't have enough ability to check if it receives a value instead of another filter.

Edit: `|` is left-associative, maybe a right-associative design will get half the results with twice the effort. and as @Jarod42 said, unconstraint `operator|` is dangerous. a better way is to make all your filters and the results of `filter | filter` under the constraint of a concept (maybe named `isFilter`?), so that you can `filter | filter | ... filter` and even `filter | filter | ... filter | value`.

Comment: Wrong usage of `std::invocable`, as OP.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, there is also the misuse of `std::invocable`, I didn't fix it because it's not the key problem. OP seems to check the *invocability* to distinguish  `filter | value` and `filter | filter`, which may be a design problem.

Comment: Better to not use constraints than using wrong constraints. (using `std::invocable<char>` in OP's case would be at least partially correct, See my answer for a correct way)

Comment: @Jarod42 you're right about `std::invocable` and `unconstraint operator|` but these were not the key point
@RedFog "right-associative design will get half the results with twice the effort" ... you meant the other way around? otherwise why mentioning it?
Right-associative design means either:
- use a right-associative operator (like `|=`): `pipe = first |= ... |= last;`
- or reverting filters order: `pipe = last | ... | first;`
Am I right?

Comment: @Solo yes, using right-associative operator or reverting the order will be also OK, but I also suggest *making all your filters and **the results of `filter | filter`** under the constraint of a concept*, it's safe and easy to define operations and laws for them. and the better way what I mentioned is by ***expression templates***, which means `filter | filter` is also a filter, and furthermore with law of association, like `(filter | filter) | (filter | filter)`.

Comment: @RedFog I edited OP to add a 2nd solution based on your suggestion, I hope I'm close to what it should be. I didn't nailed (yet) the case `filter|filter...|filter` (left associative operator with left to right pipelining) but it is much better, clearer and safer anyway. Many thanks!

Comment: @Solo It can not be better. note that `|` (or your `+=`) has the law of association, `filter | filter | filter` is equal to `filter | (filter | filter)`, which allows your to use any binary operator - that's the significance.

Comment: I tried to implement `filter|...|filter|value` but without success! Using a right associative operator (like `+=`) is close enough to what I wanted (only the "natural" pipe operator `|` couldn't be used). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `Filter2<decltype(Filter1)> filter2;` is wrong, it would be `Filter2<decltype(pipe1)> filter2;` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GeErv5cro).

but simpler would be to move `F` from class parameter to function parameter:

```
struct EolFilter{//chainable multi-functor; adds an EOL after each char
    template<typename F, typename...Args>
    requires(std::invocable<F, Args&&...>)
    void operator()(const F& f, Args&&...args)const{//pass-through unchanged
        printf("EolFilter::operator()(Args&&...args)\n");
        f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }

    template<std::invocable<char> F>
    void operator()(const F& f, char c)const{
        printf("EolFilter::operator()(char '%c')\n", c);
        f(c);
        f('\n');
    }
};
struct VowelFilter{//chainable multi-functor; filters out vowels
    template<typename F, typename...Ts>
    requires(std::invocable<F, Ts&&...>)
    void operator()(const F& f, Ts&&...args)const{//pass-through unchanged
        f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }

    template<std::invocable<char> F>
    void operator()(const F& f, char c)const{//
        if(c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u'){
            //f("VOWEL");//skip or do something special for this case
        }else{
            f(c);//pass-through unchanged
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MT6Pa3s4E)

Note: `std::invocable` usage fixed.

Note: `unconstraint operator|` is dangerous, you should probably follow advice from your previous question [generic-multi-functor-composition-pipelining-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68021778/2684539).